# form submit not work correctly on iPad

Tags: jquery, forms, ipad

I have a form:

```
  <form id="pay_form"  action='@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogonUrl"]' method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="Signed" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="email" size="50" maxlength="50" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="Language" value="en">
                <input id="pay_confirm_order" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary pull-right" value="Submit"/>
     </form>
```

This is js code which handle form submit:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#pay_confirm_order', function () {
        fillEpayForm();
    });
```

When user click `Sumbit` button I make ajax request:

```
function fillEpayForm() {
        var url = getCultureUrl('/pay/FillEpayForm?' + Math.random());

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#pay_form').find('input[name="Signed"]').val(data.signedString);
                $('#pay_form').find('input[name="email"]').val(data.email);
                $('#pay_form').submit();
            },
            async: false
        });
    }
```

The `action` attribute contains external URL (this is bank service which recieve post requests).
When form is submited than opens bank's site. All works fine on the desktop browsers and android. But on iPad3 the address bar is changed but the page not change. How to solve this? This is problem only on iOS6, on 5.1 version all works fine.

Comment: There's likely a javascript error on the iPad that's killing your script. You'll need to debug it using remove web inspector or weinre.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: There are no js errors

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function fillEpayForm() {
    var url = getCultureUrl('/pay/FillEpayForm?' + Math.random());

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#pay_form').find('input[name="Signed"]').val(data.signedString);
            $('#pay_form').find('input[name="email"]').val(data.email);
            $('#pay_form').submit();
        },
        async: false
    });
    return false;
}
$(document).on('click', '#pay_confirm_order', function () {
    return fillEpayForm();
});
```

Comment: Is your ajax function working? After calling `fillEpayForm();` add an `alert('test');`

Comment: I made some changes in my answer try it.

Answer (score 0):

I had some serious mproblem with the ipad because it caches hole views. I solved my problem by using

```
[OutputCache(Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

as attribute for my base controller, it may help you.